# SQL select max ids from two tables for a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, max

I am trying to select a set of Ids that match certain criteria and I am struggling to write the SQL query that will return what I want.

Table 1:

```
SelloutPriceID|SiteID|CountryCode|CurrencyCode|RequestID|RequestDateTime|InsertedDateTime
666|1002|BE|EUR|12504|2016-09-02 11:57:12.0000000|2016-11-14 14:27:35.980
667|1002|BE|EUR|12501|2016-09-02 11:57:12.0000000|2016-11-14 14:27:36.600
668|1002|BE|EUR|12507|2016-09-02 11:57:12.0000000|2016-11-14 14:27:36.963
```

Table 2:

```
SelloutPricesAuditID|RequestID|SiteID|CountryCode|InsertedDateTime
1|128|1002|BE|2016-11-14 16:55:29.543
2|12507|1002|BE|2016-11-14 17:07:16.633
```

I am trying to group by siteId and countryCode on both tables then only get the max request id for that group. Then join the tables together matching on the Site id and country code and max request id.

If the left table row isn't in the right table I want it to be returned. 
If the request id of the right table is not equal to the maxRequestID of the left table I want that row return.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT s.*, spa2.*
FROM [SPS_selloutprices].[SelloutPrices] as s WITH (NOLOCK)

inner join (select sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode, Max(sp.RequestID) as maxrequestid 
            from SPS_selloutprices.SelloutPrices sp
            group by sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode
            ) s2
            on s2.SiteID = s.SiteID and s.CountryCode = s2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = s.RequestID

full join (select spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode, MAX(spa.RequestID) as maxrequestid
           from sps_pricealerts.SelloutPricesAudit spa
           group by spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode
           ) spa2
           on s.SiteID = spa2.SiteID and s.CountryCode = spa2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = spa2.maxrequestid
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I came up with in the end and it works how I want it to, if you have ways to improve it I would like to hear your suggestions.

```
SELECT s.*, spa2.*
FROM [SPS_selloutprices].[SelloutPrices] as s WITH (NOLOCK)

inner join (select sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode, Max(cast(sp.RequestID as int)) as maxrequestid 
            from SPS_selloutprices.SelloutPrices sp
            group by sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode
            ) s2
            on s2.SiteID = s.SiteID and s.CountryCode = s2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = s.RequestID

full join (select spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode, spa.IsRetrieved, max(cast(spa.RequestID as int)) as maxrequestid
           from sps_pricealerts.SelloutPricesAudit spa
           group by spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode, spa.IsRetrieved
           ) spa2
           on s.SiteID = spa2.SiteID and s.CountryCode = spa2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = spa2.maxrequestid
where ((s.RequestID <> spa2.maxrequestid or spa2.maxrequestid is null)
or (spa2.IsRetrieved <> 1 or spa2.IsRetrieved is null))
and s.CountryCode = @countryCode
```

Comment: if your full join returns only the right hand record, then s2.maxrequestid is NULL - so that row does not INNER JOIN back and disappears - if that is an issue - you might want to check

Answer (score 0):

to try to reflect the FULL OUTER JOIN in use - was thinking of

```
        SELECT s.*, spa2.*
    FROM [SPS_selloutprices].[SelloutPrices] as s 

    inner join (select sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode, Max(sp.RequestID) as maxrequestid 
                from SPS_selloutprices.SelloutPrices sp
                group by sp.SiteID, sp.CountryCode
                ) s2
                on  s2.SiteID = s.SiteID and s.CountryCode = s2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = s.RequestID
                  OR spa2.SiteID = s.SiteID and s.CountryCode = spa2.CountryCode and spa2.maxrequestid = s.RequestID

    full join (select spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode, MAX(spa.RequestID) as maxrequestid
               from sps_pricealerts.SelloutPricesAudit spa
               group by spa.SiteID, spa.CountryCode
               ) spa2
               on s.SiteID = spa2.SiteID and s.CountryCode = spa2.CountryCode and s2.maxrequestid = spa2.maxrequestid
```